# Find model using uuid in laravel7

Tags: uuid, laravel-7

It sounds like trivial but I have been searching for a while and I didn't find a suitable answer!!
How to get a model using uuid inside my controller? I have tried `find` and `where('uuid', $uuid)` but it always gets a null value!

Code

```
public function index()
{
    $uuid = '90236239-5f28-4d74-948e-eb6c921b323c';
    return User::where('uuid', $uuid)->first();
```

Part of the model

```
use App\Traits\UuidTrait;

class Userextends BaseModel
{

    use UuidTrait;

    protected $casts = [
         'uuid' => EfficientUuid::class,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by

```
whereUuid($uuid)->first();
```